# Midpoint coordinates from line in Field Calculator (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line

I'm looking for a way to collect the mid-point coordinates of my LineString type Shapefile using the Field Calculator.

What I've already tried was `x(centroid($geometry))`, but this calculates the mean position of the line.

The Geometry panel from the Field Calculator has an `end_point` and `start_point` option. Is there a `mid_point` function that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want the coordinate of the point on the line at half the line length?

Comment: try with `line_interpolate_point($geometry, $length/2)` will draw the midpoint along the line

Comment: Yes, what i want is the coordinate values at half the line length. I tried your option @pigreco, but I'm using Field Calculator from the Attribute Table. Could I use `$length/2` for this same purpose?

Comment: yes, `$length` calculates the length of the line respecting the project settings. For corrdinate just write `x (line_interpolate_point ($geometry, $length / 2))`, same thing for y

Comment: Thanks @pigreco! It worked just fine! Now I'm just curious. In order to draw the midpoint along the line do I have to create a whole new layer? Or the point would be embedded into my lines? Virtual layers are used for something like this?

Comment: You can add the midpoint to a line by adding a style layer and use the geometry generator with the expression above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To plot the midpoint of a polyline using the field calc:

```
line_interpolate_point ($geometry, $length / 2)
```

To visualize the point, add a style layer with the geometry generator:

[image]

**$length:**
Returns the length of a linestring. If you need the length of a border of a polygon, use $perimeter instead. The length calculated by this function respects both the current project's ellipsoid setting and distance unit settings. For example, if an ellipsoid has been set for the project then the calculated length will be ellipsoidal, and if no ellipsoid is set then the calculated length will be planimetric.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#length